# add/combine columns after searching in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to copy data from different columns to a particular column in the same DataFrame.

| Index | col1A | col2A | colB | list | CT | CW | CH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | : |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | b |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 |  | 2 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 |  |  | 3d |  |  |  |  |

But prior to that I wanted to search if those columns(col1A,col2A,colB) exist in the DataFrame and group those columns which are present and move the grouped data to relevant columns(CT,CH,etc) like,

|  |  |  |  | CH | CW | CT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |  |  | 1 |  |  |
| 1 | b |  |  | b |  |  |
| 2 |  | 2 |  | 2 |  |  |
| 3 |  |  | 3d |  |  | 3d |

I did,

```
col_list1 = ['ColA','ColB','ColC'] 
test1 = any([ i in df.columns for i in col_list1 ])
if test1==True:
    df['CH'] = df['Col1A'] +df['Col2A'] 
    df['CT'] = df['ColB']
```

this code is throwing me a keyerror
.
I want it to ignore columns that are not present and add only those that are present

Comment: As written your question is unclear.  Can you illustrate what you want by providing a sample of the starting dataframe and an example of what you want to get.  Be sure to illustrate the issue you seem to be having with a column not existing in your list of desired columns

Comment: I've edited the question. Kindly check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use Python `set` or `Series.isin` to find the common columns

```py
cols = list(set(col_list1) & set(df.columns))
# or
cols = df.columns[df.columns.isin(col_list1)]
df['CH'] = df[cols].sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: this is working fine if the data in 'col_list' are of same type. But I typically have integers and strings mixed up.  This code is not throwing any error but it is not working! kindly help me

Comment: @Surya_Jas You should give more detail since I don't think this won't work on different types.

Comment: I've edited the code . kindly look into it

Comment: @Surya_Jas You need `all` not `any` in your code.

Comment: I used this part                                  
  cols = df.columns[df.columns.isin(col_list1)]
df['CH'] = df[cols].sum(axis=1).               it works fine if the data in a column is of same type! can you help me how to tweak this code to facilitate multiple data types in a same column

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just concatenating the columns with `+`, collect them into a list and use `sum` with `axis=1`:

```
df['CH'] = np.sum([df[c] for c in cl if c in df], axis=1)
```